How to determine the cut-off frequency for a Gaussian filter in a reasonable way using frequency spectrum analysis?
I have 100Hz data, which is upsampled to 500 Hz using Cubic spline interpolation.
Subsequently, I would like to smooth this upsampled data using filtering, but I struggle to find an objective basis for my argument concerning the magnitude of the cut-off frequency.
I have tried using frequency spectrum analysis, but based on the visual inspection of the filtered signal, it has resulted in cut-off frequencies that seem too low for my purpose. However, it might be possible that I just couldn't evaluate the used threshold frequency/amplitude well, since I do not know how to do that correctly.
Briefly, I created frequencies and the amplitude spectrum using FFT in Python and identified the 'optimal' cut-off frequency as the highest significant frequency, where the corresponding amplitude equals the set threshold amplitude (I have made attempts with 5% and 10% of the maximum amplitude as a threshold).
After this, I calculated $\sigma$ for the Gaussian filter as:
$$\sigma = 1/2\pi f_{cutoff}.$$
However, this resulted in seemingly too low sigmas, on the order of $10^{-2}$, and seemingly no smoothing effect. By looking at the output, based on the effect of different $\sigma$ values on the raw signal, I would expect an optimal smoothing around $\sigma = 1$:

As a saving option, I was thinking about using a Savitzky-Golay filter, which has worked fine with the data but as I know, it is even more difficult to mathematically reason the implementation of a specific window size for that one, than reasoning selected $\sigma$ for the Gaussian.
I am open to any solution other than a Gaussian filter too. I have been considering using a 2nd order low-pass bidirectional Butterworth filter and cutoff frequencies derived through the same method were working better with that one. However, I do not know how the selected threshold amplitude should be reasoned in this case (by looking at the filtered signal, the filter was working properly around a threshold amplitude of 2-3% of the maximal amplitude).
As I was trying to emphasize, I am rather looking for a filter whose configuration (i.e., cutoff frequency) can be supported mathematically, and I am also able to show that, than comparing the performance of filters on my data.
Please note, that I have no professional background in engineering.
EDIT: Plot showing the effect of a Gaussian filter ($\sigma = 0.8$) on the upsampled data (i.e., 500 Hz):


related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79207548/determination-of-cutoff-frequency-for-filtering


which is upsampled to 500 Hz using Cubic spline interpolation

I think this is your problem. If you up-sample "properly" no further smoothing should be required (unless the original data needs smoothing). The best way to undo the damage of spline-based up-sampling is to not do it in the first place.
Correct up-sampling is easy enough: insert 4 zeros between each sample and run that through a lowpass filter with a cutoff frequency of about 50 Hz (the original Nyquist frequency).
The exact choice of the "best" lowpass filter depends on  the properties of your signal(s) and the application requirements. It's a trade off between

Flat amplitude pass band
Flat phase or group delay in the pass band
Tolerance to residual aliasing
Causality, latency and transient preservation.
Resources: CPU, memory, power consumption, etc.
etc.

In many cases good choices are Butterworth filters for causal up-sampling or Kaiser Window based FIR filters for  linear phase up-sampling.

Thank you for your answer. Can you please explain, what you mean under the damage of spline-based upsampling? Furthermore, motivated by your answer, I edited the original post by including a plot showing upsampled and filtered and only upsampled data for two datasets. Can you please evaluate the potential necessity of filtering and the 'goodness' of cubic spline upsampling based on these?

@MártonHorváth: Upsampling is a mathematically well defined operation. Provided the original signal is sampled without aliasing, the function is uniquely defined at ALL times, not just at the sample times. That means there is only one correct answer for any up sampling operation and spline interpolation won't give you that answer. The interpolation error is data dependent and hard to predict.

Thank you @Hilmar, this is a useful comment!
